# Delete an Insert Into Table statement after it has been applied MySql

Tags: mysql

I inserted several smaller tables into a larger table.

If for example, some time later, I would like to delete the data from the large table (MI_TOTAL) and only the data that is corresponding to one small table such as (MI_APR) is there anyway this can be done ?

I do not have a column in the small table (MI_APR) that can allow me to differentiate between other small tables.

```
INSERT INTO MI_TOTAL
SELECT * FROM MI_APR;
INSERT INTO MI_TOTAL
SELECT * FROM MI_MAY;
```

Comment: Does the `MI_APR` table have a primary key?

Comment: @Barmar no I do not. Do you suggest me to add one ?

Comment: update your question and add  your tables  schema

Comment: Yes, I suggest you do it. Then you can simply do `DELETE t FROM MI_TOTAL t JOIN MI_APR a ON t.column = a.column`, where `column` is the PK of `MI_APR`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm pretty sure this approach would only work if each child-table had DIFFERENT unique primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a column in MI_TOTAL to identify its source, even if it is a date column with 'date loaded' for example. If the Child tables contain a date that is unique to it's name i.e. MI_APR has only dates in April then you can use that:

`DELETE FROM MI_TOTAL WHERE MONTH(MI_TOTAL.datecol)=4`

It looks like the child tables are month related, so why not add an Int column to hold the month relevant to the inserted data, then it becomes easy.  Or a string column with the name of the source table to be really explicit:

`DELETE FROM MI_TOTAL WHERE source='MI_APR';`

The advantage of this approach is that you can also filter any search on the TOTAL table using this column also